# Unweave sequence, Kotlin functional/streaming idiom

Tags: kotlin, sequences, purely-functional

I have a sequence of interleaved data (with fixed stride) and I'd like to reduce it to a single value for each "structure" (n*stride values to n values).

I could just use loop writing into the mutable list with selected step for reader index, but I'm looking for more functional and readable approach. Any thoughts?

For example: 
Input sequence consists of RGB triplets (stride 3) and output is grayscale.

Imperative way is like:

```
fun greyscale(stream:List<Byte>):List<Byte>{
    val out = ArrayList(stream.size / 3)
    var i = 0; var o = 0
    while(i < stream.size)
        out[o++]=(stream[i++] + stream[i++] + stream[i++])/3
    return out
}
```

How can I make something like that without explicitly implementing a function and mutable container, but purely on functional extensions like `.map` and so on?

Comment: `map/reduce/flatMap` ? i'm afraid I don't quite understand what you want to do. whats your input and desired output?

Comment: your question is too broad. could you describe it clearly?

Comment: added example. The question isn't broad, it's rather abstract because it's about idiom/pattern to be used for more than a single problem.

Comment: Kotlin 1.2-M1 (EAP) defines new functions that will help with this. Namely `windowed(size: Int, step: Int)` but also `chunked(size: Int)` and `pairwise()` for similar scenarios. See [Early access program for Kotlin 1.2 has been started | Kotlin Blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/06/early-access-program-for-kotlin-1-2-has-been-started/) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin 1.2 (Milestone 1 was released yesterday) brings the `chunked` method on collections. It chunks up the collection into blocks of a given size. You can use this to implement your function:

```
fun greyscale(stream: List<Byte>): List<Byte> = 
      stream.chunked(3)
            .map { (it.sum() / 3).toByte() }
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible way would be grouping by the index of the elements (in this case `/3`) and mapping these groups to their sum.

```
stream.withIndex()
      .groupBy { it.index / 3 }
      .toSortedMap()
      .values
      .map { (it.sumBy { it.value } / 3).toByte() }
```

Also strictly functional, but using Rx, would be possible by using [`window(long)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#window(long))

```
Observable.from(stream)
          .window(3)
          .concatMap { it.reduce(Int::plus).toObservable() }
          .map { (it / 3).toByte() }
```

Comment: Not at all. :) and no need `toSortedMap` since the map is ordered as iteration order.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @marstran's answer, in Kotlin 1.2 you can use `chunked` function, but providing the transform lambda to it:

```
fun greyscale(stream: List<Byte>): List<Byte> = 
      stream.chunked(3) { it.average().toByte() }
```

This variant has an advantage that it doesn't instantiate a new List for every triple, but rather creates a single List and reuses it during the entire operation.

Answer (score 0):

### Excludes remaining elements:

```
const val N = 3
fun greyscale(stream: List<Byte>) = (0 until stream.size / N)
        .map { it * N }
        .map { stream.subList(it, it + N).sum() / N }
        .map(Int::toByte)
```

**Output**

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  => [2, 5]
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  => [2]

### Includes remaining elements:

```
const val N = 3
fun greyscale(stream: List<Byte>) = (0 until (stream.size + N - 1) / N)
        .map { it * N }
        .map { stream.subList(it, minOf(stream.size, it + N)).sum() / N }
        .map(Int::toByte)
```

**Output**

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  => [2, 5]
>
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  => [2, 3]

Answer (score 0):

Best what I'm capable of is this:

```
fun grayscale(rgb:List<Byte>):List<Byte>
    = rgb.foldIndexed(
        IntArray(rgb.size / 3),
        { idx, acc, i -> 
            acc[idx / 3] = acc[idx / 3] + i; acc
        }).map{ (it / 3).toByte() }
```

#### Output

> in: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>
> out: [2, 5]

And variations with `ArrayList` with `add` and `last`